# Automated Batch Numbering in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have several columns with data, but I want a VBA script that can copy the data from Column 9 (Job Numbers), put it in Column 1 (Batch Numbers) and create automated batch numbering starting at 20. If it search through the existing data and find a previous batch 20 it must mark the next one as 21 and so on e.g. 15845-02-06/20....15845-02-06/21....15860-05-01/20, etc

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting Question. *One way* to handle this is to have a batch file export the excel (or vbs but batch is way easier) or you can do it manually then you may get the program to draw from the file

ex: (Batch Code UTF-8)
*

```
set RUNCHB=1
set /p RUNCHB=<".\Variables\RUNCHB.dll"
::OR set /p RUNCHB=<<".\Variables\RUNCHB.dll"
echo %RUNCHB%
pause >nul
exit
```

Comment: Your answer was most helpful. Thank you so much for taking the time to help!